# jdbc-user-service not working properly

Tags: java, mysql, spring-mvc, jdbc, spring-security

I have a problem with SpringSecurity. That's my controller:

```
@Secured({ "user", "administrator" })
    @RequestMapping("/profile")
    public String profile(HttpServletRequest request) {
        return "profile";
    }
```

When I use:

```
<authentication-manager>
        <authentication-provider>
            <user-service>
                <user name="user" password="user" authorities="user" />
            </user-service>
        </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>
```

,log in as an user and go to /profile, profile page is displayed. But when I use:

```
<authentication-manager>
        <authentication-provider>
            <jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSource"
                users-by-username-query="SELECT LOGIN, PASSWORD, EMAIL FROM USER WHERE LOGIN=?"
                authorities-by-username-query="SELECT U.LOGIN, UT.NAME FROM USER U, USER_TYPE UT WHERE U.USER_TYPE_ID = UT.ID AND U.LOGIN =?  " />
        </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>
```

,log in to the system as an user and go to /profile, page profile is not displayed(of course I sign up before log in).
This is a piece of my database script:

```sql
CREATE TABLE USER_TYPE
(
    ID SMALLINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    NAME VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE USER
(
    ID BIGINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    EMAIL VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    LOGIN VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    PASSWORD VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    USER_TYPE_ID SMALLINT NOT NULL DEFAULT 2
);

ALTER TABLE USER
ADD CONSTRAINT USER_ID_USER_TYPE
foreign key(USER_TYPE_ID) REFERENCES  USER_TYPE(ID) ON DELETE CASCADE;

INSERT INTO USER_TYPE VALUES(1, 'administrator');
INSERT INTO USER_TYPE VALUES(2, 'user');
```

I really have no idea, what I am doing wrong. Please help me! Maybe it's because of my login page? A piece of code of my log in controller:

```
@RequestMapping("/postLogin")
    public String postLogin(HttpServletRequest request, @ModelAttribute("userDto") @Valid UserDTO userDto,
            BindingResult result) throws Exception {
        HttpSession session = request.getSession();
        UserEntity user = dao.findByLoginAndPassword(userDto.getLogin(), SHA1Encoder.getEncodeWord(userDto.getPassword()));
        session.setAttribute("User", user);
        return "redirect:/home";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String welcome(Model model, HttpServletRequest request) {
        UserDTO user = new UserDTO();
        model.addAttribute("userDto", user);
        return "index";
    }
```

And piece of code of my index.jsp page:

```
<form:form action="/Webapp/postLogin" method="POST" modelAttribute="userDto">         
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <form:input type="text" path="login" value="" placeholder="Login"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <form:input type="password" path="password" value="" placeholder="Password"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="submit" value="Log in" name="submit"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</form:form>
```

That's my piece of security-context.xml:

```
<http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
        <form-login login-page="/" default-target-url="/home"
            authentication-failure-url="/?error=1" username-parameter="login"
            password-parameter="password" />
        <logout logout-success-url="/signUp" />
        <csrf />
</http>
```

**Edit login page:**

```
<c:set var="loginUrl"><c:url value="/login"/></c:set>
    <form:form action="${loginUrl}" method="POST" modelAttribute="userDto">       
        <table>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <form:input type="text" path="login" value="" placeholder="Login"/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <form:input type="password" path="password" value="" placeholder="Password"/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}" value="${_csrf.token}"/>
                        <input type="submit" value="Log in" name="submit"/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </form:form>
```

And change user_type.name values for ROLE_USER and ROLE_ADMIN and @Secured({ "ROLE_USER", "ROLE_ADMINISTRATOR" })

Comment: Error message? Logs?

Comment: I change my login page:

Comment: I suspect sth with query <jdbc-user-service is bad or with login page